# INNER JOIN mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I have this code which I use to get the number of subscribers:

```
SELECT provider_id,subcat_id, COUNT(user_id) AS subscribers 
  FROM subscribers WHERE subcat_id=5 
    AND provider_id=provider_id 
  GROUP BY provider_id 
  ORDER BY subscribers DESC LIMIT 10
```

`provider_id` is a foreign key to the providers table which contains the `provider_name`.

How can I get the results which obtains the foreign key value for provider_id and replaces it with the provider_name from table providers?  I tried an inner join, but it didn't work. It is probably a syntax error as my select query is a bit complicated.

The results I get now are:

```
+----------+---------+-----------+
|provder_id|subcat_id|subscribers|
+----------+---------+-----------+
|2         |5        |5          |
+----------+---------+-----------+
|4         |5        |3          |
+----------+---------+-----------+
|1         |5        |1          |
+----------+---------+-----------+
```

However, what I want is:

```
+----------+-------------+---------+-----------+
|provder_id|provider_name|subcat_id|subscribers|
+----------+-------------+---------+-----------+
|2         |Alex         |5        |5          |
+----------+-------------+---------+-----------+
```

SELECT subscribers.provider_id,subscribers.subcat_id, COUNT(user_id) AS subscribers FROM subscribers JOIN providers ON subscribers.provider_id=providers.provider_name WHERE subscribers.subcat_id=5 AND subscribers.provider_id=subscribers.provider_id GROUP BY subscribers.provider_id ORDER BY subscribers DESC LIMIT 10

that doesnt work

SOLVED IT WITH

SELECT s.provider_id,p.provider_name, s.subcat_id, COUNT(s.user_id) AS subscribers FROM subscribers s JOIN providers p ON s.provider_id=p.provider_id WHERE s.subcat_id=5 AND s.provider_id=s.provider_id GROUP BY provider_id ORDER BY subscribers DESC LIMIT 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  p.provider_id,
  provider.name,
  subcat_id,
  COUNT(user_id) AS subscribers 
FROM subscribers s
JOIN provider p ON p.provider_id = s.provider.id
WHERE subcat_id = 5
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
ORDER BY 4 DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Note the use of:

- aliases for tables for cleaner distinction of common column names,
- group by that lists all non-aggregate columns (your current query would not work properly)

Comment: SELECT subscribers.provider_id,subscribers.subcat_id, COUNT(user_id) AS subscribers FROM subscribers JOIN providers ON subscribers.provider_id=providers.provider_name WHERE subscribers.subcat_id=5 AND subscribers.provider_id=subscribers.provider_id GROUP BY subscribers.provider_id ORDER BY subscribers DESC LIMIT 10

Comment: this doesnt give any errors but it doesnt produce any results too '(

Comment: Do you have any rows in your `providers` table? Specifically for provider_id 2 (Alex)?

Comment: yes. providers table hold information about providers.. Alex exists in it

Comment: better post your raw data then, or even better create an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with schema and data and post the link in your question

Answer (score 0):

not quite sure what your code is but what you need to do is... lets say you have Table A and Table B. I am guessing Provider_id is your linking ID

```
    Select TableA.provder_id,
    TableB.subcat_id,
    TableA.Name,
    Count(user_id) as subscribers)
    FROM TableA
    INNER JOIN TableB
    ON TableB.provder_id = TableA.provider_id
WHERE subcat_id = 5
GROUP BY TableA.Provider_id,
TableB.Provider_id,
TableA.Name
```

As you are using "count" you need to group by on all fields

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick for you:

```
SELECT provider_id,provider.name, subcat_id, COUNT(user_id) AS subscribers 
FROM subscribers 
JOIN provider ON provider_id = provider.id
WHERE subcat_id=5 
GROUP BY provider_id 
ORDER BY subscribers DESC 
LIMIT 10
```