# MySQL link data from two tables

Tags: mysql, rows

I have a query that gives me the three most active mod_id's in the past 7 days.
This query works fine.

It is the following query:

```
SELECT `mod_id`, COUNT(`mod_id`) m from `history_spottings` WHERE `created` BETWEEN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 604800) AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP())
GROUP BY `mod_id`
ORDER BY m DESC
limit 3;
```

Now I get as a output 3 mod_id's and the #.

How do I link the mod_id's to their usernames from a different table?

The other table is called `user` and looks like this:

[image: user table]

The user_id is identical to the mod_id from my history_spottings table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INNER JOIN mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150458/inner-join-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

If Both table has user_id column. Then use ***JOIN*** query.

The best way is use **JOIN** query.

[Mysql Join Query](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)